# iOS Library Can't Find Header

Tags: ios, react-native, segment

I'm trying to integrate Segment analytics with a React Native wrapper library (react-native-segment-analytics). The core Segment iOS library has been added as a Pod (Using `use_frameworks!`); the wrapper library I've dropped SegmentAnalytics.xcodeproj into `Libraries/`.

The error I'm running into is

> .../node_modules/react-native-segment-analytics/ios/SegmentAnalytics/Classes/SegmentAnalytics.m:7:9: fatal error: 'Analytics/SEGAnalytics.h' file not found

The line in question is

`#import <Analytics/SEGAnalytics.h>`

[image: Libraries]

[image: SEGAnalytics.h]

I'm pretty confident this isn't specific to Segment, but I'm leaving that here just in case.

The header is available in the project. In fact I can add this same `#import` in a source file in the root of the project and it resolves fine. The only difference I can discern is that the wrapper library is an embedded xcodeproj.

I've been banging my head going through seemingly every Xcode config option trying to resolve this, including trying different Header Search Paths and Framework Search Paths, trying to add the Segment library as a linked binary everywhere I could think, and even changing the import from <> to "" syntax.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: Libraries used:

**Edit2**: Added some text to try and clarify Segment vs the react-native-segment-analytics lib.

https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ios

https://github.com/charlires/react-native-segment-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Try to use installation [instructions](https://github.com/smore-inc/react-native-segment-io-analytics) from developer of this library:

> **Installation**
>
> 1. Download and install the npm package by running npm install --save react-native-segment-io-analytics
> 2. In your Podfile, add pod "Analytics" to your project and run pod install in your ios folder
> 3. Inside Xcode (make sure you've opened your .xcworkspace file), go to the project navigator and right click Libraries -> Add Files to [your project's name].
> 4. Go to node_modules -> react-native-segment-io-analytics -> and choose the RNSegmentIOAnalytics.xcodeproj file.
>    Make sure your project links to libAnalytics.a and libRNSegmentIOAnalytics.a (The libraries should be listed under "Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries").

Probably, you've missed some steps.

Comment: The library used was https://github.com/charlires/react-native-segment-analytics (updated in original post). I changed from adding the RN wrapped as a Pod to just embedding the xcodeproj because our project includes React Native natively (not as a Cocoapod), and we ran into other dependency issues not adding a Pod for `React`.

Comment: Still not clear for me one thing: you've added SegmentAnalitics as project dependency, and you've added react-native-segment-analytics as pod dependency? or vice versa? Because on your first screenshot SegmentAnalitics is project dependency.

Comment: It does read a little weird. I will update the original post, but SegmentAnalytics.xcodeproj === react-native-segment-analytics, Analytics === Segment's iOS lib.

Comment: Ok, so i've dig into this theme a bit (react native apps). And as i've understood you can't simply add this library into your project. For better understanding of your problem please refer to [react native integration guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html). You'll see, that you'll need to create your own podfile for React, and after that, i guess, i'll have no problems with integrating segment-analytics library. I've made a test, i've initialised react app as it's described in getting started guide, and integrate library with npm. It worked.

Comment: Appreciate the input. We ended up redoing a lot of our project setup to get things working.

Comment: Please, no problem )

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of trial and error, I just couldn't get the library linked and having visibility to the Segment Analytics Pod file dependency. I ended up removing all of the 3rd party modules we had linked in the project and switched to adding them all as CocoaPods. This significantly simplified our iOS project file (no more managing changes to Search Header Paths or linked libs/frameworks).

Worth mentioning:

- Switching to pulling in all RN dependencies via CocoaPods required adding most of the [React Subspecs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React.podspec) to get things working the same as before.
- I ran into cache hell in this migration. tl;dr Purge all node_modules, Pods, Derived Data, and iOS build folders.
- I had to comment out `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile. Otherwise I ran into `fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found` errors. Googling led to dead ends.